# Как упростить код python по подсчету и сравнению сумм?

Tags: python

Задача
-Серийный номер автомобиля состоит из 8 цифр. Посчитайте, сколько серийных номеров, у которых сумма первых четырех цифр равна сумме последних 4 цифр.
Написал простой код, но понял, что мне его не скомпилировать.
a - это первые 4 числа, b - последние 4 чсила.

```
a = 0
b = 0
x = 0
final = 0
while x != 99999999:
    x += 1
    b += 1
    if b == 10000:
        b = 0
        a += 1
    if sum(map(int, str(a))) == sum(map(int, str(b))):
        final += 1
print(final)
```

Его можно упростить или лучше делать совсем по-другому?

Comment: Это переформулированная [задача о счастливых билетах](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85), в интернете про неё вроде много инфы должно быть

Comment: Ну вообще Google Colab обещает минуты за 3 этот код выполнить, ну подождать немного, подумаешь )

Comment: За 3.5 минуты посчиталось, выдало 4816029, не знаю, правильный ли ответ, но код выполняется за вполне допустимое время. Хотя я сделал бы через два вложенных `for ... in range`, так было бы понятнее.

Comment: @CrazyElf да ответ правильный, спасибо за помощь в следующий раз буду пользоваться Google Colab

Comment: А если запихать вычисление `sum(map(int, str(a)))` в отдельную функцию и задекорировать её `functools.lru_cache`, то вообще меньше минуты считает. Так то Colab не быстрый, просто я там всё делаю - удобно, ну и как референс по скорости и т.д., мощный локальный комп гораздо быстрее будет считать, а там всего два ядра (но много памяти зато).